# GMail prefixes the anchor tag id

Tags: html, gmail, gmail-api, strip, froala

I am using Froala WYSIWYG to design an email template. Once I send out the email, my service sends out a body with all the tags having an id structure of `hello-1234-{index}` where index is the nth a tag in the body. But my GMail inbox receives `m_779662563892484459hello-1234-{index}`. The prefix changes with each send, another time i received `m_1624206567182207259hello-1234-{index}`.

Why does GMail add the prefix `m_779662563892484459` to my a tag ids? Is there a way to remove it.

This [article](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps-2/) provides tips for developing on GMail but does not mentions this behavior.